# Make Bootstrap dropdown from loop in python/Django

Tags: css, python-3.x, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu that shows a list of items from a loop. I can view the source for the page and the loop is generating links, but the drop down button doesn't appear to do (display) anything when clicked on.

I am working with python 3 and Django. The template is below.

```
{% extends "a/header.html" %}

{% block content %}


<div class="dropdown">

<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" 
type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" 
aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
People
<span class="caret"></span>
  </button>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">

    {% for group in object_list %}
        <li><a href="/a/people/{{group.id}}">{{group.name}}</a></li>

    {% endfor %}

  </ul>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding these two lines at the bottom of the a/header.html seems to have solved the specific dropdown issue.

```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```